# Добавление panel в panel-group bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Пытаюсь создать новую категорию. Отправляю ее на сервер для сохранения в базе, и если success,то хочу добавить ее ко всем остальным в panel-group. С отправкой на сервер проблем нет, но как ее потом, как ещё одну panel, добавить в panel-group, без перезагрузки страницы, я не понимаю. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.

panel-group:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="panelGroupId">
        <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category" varStatus="loop">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title row">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" class="col-sm-5"
                           data-target="#collapseIn-${category.id}">${category.name}</a>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">${category.description}</div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#editCategory"
                                onclick="showId(${category.id})">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger"
                                data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#deleteCategory"
                                onclick="showId(${category.id})">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                        </button>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseIn-${category.id}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="panel-body row">
                        <c:forEach items="${category.criteria}" var="criteria" varStatus="loop">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">${criteria.title}</div>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"
                                    onclick="showId(${criteria.id})">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                            </button>
                            <br>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
```

метод jquery:

```
$("#saveCategory").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/addCategory",
        type: "POST",
        data: {name: $("#categoryName").val(), "description": $("#categoryDescription").val()},
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#panelGroupId").add
           // Здесь как-то добавить запись к panel-group
        },
        error: function (textStatus) {
            console.log(textStatus);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: запрос добавления должен рендерить частичный шаблон панельки, и возвращать его, как часть `data`. После чего вы добавите его к панели а-ля `$("#panelGroupId").append(data.result_html)`.
Могут быть и другие варианты, но этот будет самый простой.

Comment: вы хотите сказать что в респонсе сервер должна быть что-то вроде <div class="panel panel-default"> все что между ним </div>?

Comment: И ещё вопрос, который не совсем по теме: Почему, если объявить функцию просто в <script></script>, ее можно использовать на вьюшке через onclick=functionName(), а если ее объявить в $(document).ready(function () {}); то ее просто не видно?

Comment: да, в ответе сервера надо вернуть html код. В целом, это может быть также json данные, в одном из полей которых будет html.

Comment: про второй вопрос без кода не очень понятно, но при использовании jquery не понятно, зачем писать конструкции вида `onclick=something()`, обработчики в таком случаее тоже через jquery следует прицеплять